# In the code displayed, how can I create additional student profiles (each requiring its own set of info), without repeating what I've already written?

Tags: python, performance, project

I am creating a program to mimic a database of students. While creating the necessary student profiles, I have found myself repeating lots of code. I want to optimize my code to be more efficient. What can I I do so that I do not need to repeat myself when creating each new student? (I am new to programming and Python, so I apologize in advance for my neophytic code.)

I have tried to create a function to automate the student-profile creating process, however I ran into the issue of having to reenter student profile's each time I ran the program. If I knew of a way to stop this from happening, maybe writing a function to automate this process would not be too bad. If you would like to see the function that I created, please let me know and I will happily share it.

```
# The following is the aforementioned code that I continuously have to repeat for each new student:

# Student_a (s_a) profile:

s_a = Student("9572813") # Initializing student with ID through Student class I created    
s_a.set_personal("Henry", "Friedman", "4292 Applesauce Tree Road, Angle-hill, VA, 76259", "218-250-5701") # Setting personal info through Student class    
a_per_info = s_a.get_personal()

# Setting student's courses, getting average for courses, and appending course averages to said student's grade list:

s_a.set_course("ENG1121 201902 100 90 96 78 69 100 100 92 86 89")    
a_av1 = s_a.get_course_average("ENG1121 201902")    
s_a.grades.append(s_a.g_list(a_av1))    
s_a.d_courses.pop(0) # (My Student class would not allow me to calculate the course average of more than 1 course, so I created a dummy list for student courses that I could .pop(0) from after each calculation, making it possible for the succeeding course's average to be calculated.)    
s_a.set_course("MATH1150 201903 99 88 74 67 91 100 83 72 87 100")    
a_av2 = s_a.get_course_average("MATH1150 201903")    
s_a.grades.append(s_a.g_list(a_av2))    
s_a.d_courses.pop(0)

# (This process of setting a student's courses is further repeated, but I thought it redundant to show the code.)    

# Using Student class to calculate student's letter grade for each class, grade percentage for each class, and student's overall GPA:

s_a.calc(s_a.grades)    
a_cor_info = s_a.get_courses()

# Adding accounting items to the student's profile

s_a.set_acct("Summer Tuition: ", 1423)    
s_a.set_acct("Summer Books Payment: ", 230)    
s_a.set_acct("Summer Access Code Payment: ", 100)    
s_a.set_acct("Summer Tuition Payment: ", 890)    
a_acct_info = s_a.get_acct()

# Calculating student's balance

a_bal = 1423 - (230 + 100 + 890)    
t_bal += a_bal
```

If something is not clear in this code, or if you need more code from my program, please let me know and I will clarify/post as necessary.

In conjunction with the rest of my program, this code works perfectly. I would just like to optimize it and make it so that I do not need to repeat all of the code when creating additional students.

Comment: Python has few modules to generate fake data - ie. [Faker](https://github.com/joke2k/faker)

Comment: if you create all data manually then it is faster to create list with all data (one row means one person) and then create code which use for-loop to converts all to different structure. You can save list in CSV file, edit file in text editor and read it back.